# How to save dinamically array in core data or realm in iOS And how to compare this array

Tags: swift, core-data, realm

I have an array

```
var names:[String]=["kate","son","viktor"]
```

I want to save this array in core data or Realm. This array dynamically changed

```
var names:[String]=["kate","son","viktor","sam"]
```

How to compare this arrays and print changes. For example: changes for names "*Sam*". Thanks for any help(idea) or links.

Comment: You'd do this in entirely different ways for Realm vs Core Data. It doesn't make sense to ask about both in a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Realm**, you could simply serialize/deserialize the array to `Data` (or `String`), like this:

```
class SomeModel: Object {
    dynamic var _names: Data!

    var names: [String] {
        set(value) {
            try! realm.write {
                _properties = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: [])
            }
        }
        get {
            guard _names != nil else { return [] }
            return try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: _names, options: []) as? [String] ?? []
        }
    }
}
```

This will store your array in Realm, but will not allow you to sort or query using the names in the array, obviously.

You probably better store each name in a proper model object and create a one-to-many property in the base object (using Realm's `List`)